# How to calculate physical length of a network cable using standard Linux commands?

Tags: networking

Is there an easy way to calculate the physical length of a network cable (Ethernet, Fiber, etc) using standard commands such as ping, iftop or other tools? Preferably it should work on most flavors of Unix/Linux.

Comment: Fairly certain this isn't possible.

Comment: How would you propose this be accomplished exactly?  And how would you account for differences between a brand-new cable and one that's been in service for years, laid out, rolled up, packed, unpacked, and otherwise degraded with the ravages of time and wear-and-tear?  It's like asking for a tow truck's engine to have a way to measure the tread left on one of the tires of a car being towed.  There's no way to do this.

Comment: There is also an issue of nearly unlimited network topologies.  If you are using the nearest layer 3 connection to do some sort of measurement there could be several layer 2/layer 1 devices in between meaning several runs of different cables.

Comment: I was thinking the time it takes to ping could be used to calculate physical distance, assuming the operating systems are sufficiently fast

Comment: You do not. You buy hw for it.

Comment: Related - https://serverfault.com/questions/86326/tool-to-physically-test-ethernet-cable-with-two-network-cards.

Answer (score 1):

For LAN-ish lengths of cable:

The part of the round trip delay of a packet that will purely depend on the cable will be around 10 nanoseconds per meter.

To get the length of the actually physically attached cable, you would have to have your test packets answered by the next switch or bridge; suitable protocols can probably be found with a managed switch.

10s of nanoseconds are a domain where you would need to work with compiled C or assembly code, and use cycle-counting and/or the HPET timer.

The hardware parts of both ends might introduce undefined delays; so might device drivers; so might kernel activity that interferes with what you are doing. All this could be mitigated by taking several thousand samples and discarding outliers and averaging - combined with *calibrating* the system to known lengths and brands of cable. Such calibration will at most be valid to an exact pair of device models.

If you want to find out the length of a WAN link of hundreds or thousands of kilometers, you can use the times an ordinary ping gives for a rough estimate; most cables (does not matter whether fibre or copper) will have a propagation speed between 0.5 and 0.9 times the speed of light in air - however, there will be extra delays introduced by active devices, and you cannot know what kind of cable is used.

Some networking hardware (switches, and rarely NICs) feature a builtin, simple version of a so called TDR - such hardware will be able to rather accurately measure cable lengths.

Comment: Between cable variation and interrupts, it is nearly impossible to do proper variations with plain hw and a complex OS like Linux. Either you buy a network tester on the cheap, or invest more money on something more professional.