# How to estimate ethernet cable length?

Tags: ethernet

Windows control panel has a feature to estimate the length of ethernet cable between the computer and the router. Is there a similar command in Linux?

> Cable Length: Displays the approximate length of the cable between the adapter and its link partner. If the reported cable length is different from the actual cable length, this could indicate a break in the cable. Accuracy can vary by up to 9 meters. The cable length will only be displayed when the adapter is connected to a network operating at 1000 Mbps.

[image]

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/455187/237982.  Also FYI that microsoft test is nowhere close to accurate, it can estimate cable length about as well as microsoft can estimate "time remaining".

Comment: Perhaps if NIC manufacturers start including TDR functionality into the hardware we will be able to accurately get cable lengths, short of that I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/q/1491654/332907, which is not a duplicate.

Comment: Just for reference, it's not Windows that supplies this tool; it's part of the specifics for the NIC you have  installed.

Comment: I would imagine that it is the distance to the switched hub, not router (your router may also contain a switched hub). Any timing through the switch would be unreliable, and the description says link partner (so a switched hub, another PC (point to point), a **directly** connected router, etc).